# Uncaught TypeError: downloadButton is null

Tags: javascript, button

I have added a download button on a few pages that appears after 10 seconds with this code (theme footer):

```
<script>
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download2");
    var counter = 10;
    var newElement = document.createElement("p");
    newElement.innerHTML = "10 seconds";
    var id;
    downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);
    id = setInterval(function() 
    {counter--;
    if(counter < 0) {
    newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
    clearInterval(id);
    } else {
    newElement.innerHTML = " " + counter.toString() + " seconds";
    }}, 1000);
</script>
```

It is working fine. However, on any page that doesn't have a button I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: downloadButton is null". Does that mean the script loads everywhere and on pages without a download button it throws this error?
I tried to wrap the script in a ready function with

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
});
```

but I couldn't get it to work. Can anyone help me out here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "*However, on any page that doesn't have a button [...]*" - I think you've seen your issue already ;) A simple `if (downloadButton)` (or similar) before you execute the rest of your code should solve it

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it :)

Comment: No problem :) Another solution would be to only include this block of code where it is required, but that might be a little more complicated. I'd take some time to look into that though, the `if()` is a safety check, while the inclusion conditionals is a little more logical.

Comment: Yes, that would be better I guess but I don't know how to do that right now. With the if function it works but the button appears for a second before the timer begins. Needs some time to check for the button I guess? Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an if statement to check if you downloadButton exists or not will solve your issue.

```
    <script>
    var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download2"); 
    if( downloadButton ){
      //rest of your code goes inside.
    }
    
</script>
```